# Wampserver 2.4 cannot find .mo file

Tags: translation, wampserver

I am trying to do this:
I created an isapi dll. The DLL searches a database on the server (this is not a 
web domain, it is a Windows 8 PC that is accessed remotely via its ip).
Basically the (remote) user enters a URL on its browser (xxxx.xxx.xxxx.x.dllname.dll)
and the dll should read data from a database and produce an html page to show the results
on the browser.

Sorry it's the first time I post to stackoverflow and I deleted
my question in the Edit post:
The question was:

I installed Wampserver 2.4 on Windows xp I
I try to run a DLL that I wrote by clicking on "www directory" 
and then double clicked on my DLL.
I get a window that shows a caption 
"This will append the following translations to your executable file" 
and then in the check box list below it shows 1 line 
No translations (.mo files) found"
and the ok button stays grayed.
What is happening? 
What is the "translation" it talks about?
Why do I need the translation? why Wampserver does not go on without translating? (whatever it means).

Comment: You cannot run a dll by double clicking on it using apache or for that matter explorer either. please explain what you are actually trying to do??

Comment: on the Apache web page it says that tu run an isapi dll you hwave to add to the config. file the proper handler and a couple of other

Comment: lines (sorry for the unintended break). I tried to run the dll form an html but get the result that first the dll is downloaded and if i then doble click on the downloaded file i get the same results abot the transaltions. What are these translations?